# Codeigniter TCPDF - Load Multiple PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

Current Issue:

> When i click on "Print PDF" it only show "1" PDF.

What I Have Done:

> I have set array on the URI , which means that it able to loop 2 times
>   using foreach , but problem now is that the PDF is currently showing
>   "1" time only

What I Need :

> Allow TCPDF generate 2 pdf

---

Create this thread is whated to know the idea,  i will try to solve it myself

Code

```
<?php
foreach($invoice as $row){  

$body='HTML 
XXXXXXX
Table';




$pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetTitle('Invoice');
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(10);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(10);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(10);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Invoice');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->writeHTML($body, true, false, true, false, '');


$pdf->lastPage();

//$pdf->Write(5, $tnc);
$pdf->Output('InvoceOutput'.'\.pdf', 'I' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us some code, we can't help you now. I think you forgot `addPage($page2)` somewhere

Comment: @VincentDecaux added the code in first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating and outputting your PDF inside your for loop, so 2 separate PDFs that are 1 page long are being generated. The 2nd PDF is likely overwriting the 1st PDF, leaving you with a single PDF 1 page long.

Configuring and outputting your PDF outside of the for loop should fix your issue:

```
<?php
$pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetTitle('Invoice');
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(10);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(10);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(10);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Invoice');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

foreach($invoice as $row){
    $body='HTML 
    XXXXXXX
    Table';

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($body, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->lastPage();

    //$pdf->Write(5, $tnc);
}

$pdf->Output('InvoceOutput'.'\.pdf', 'I' );
?>
```